# WORDPRESS - no Comment after server change

Tags: database, wordpress, comments

after the change to another server, I get this error when someone try to post a comment to a post:
The comment could not be saved

In the Debug Mode i get this information:
Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

In the backend I can see, that there are new comments (red point with a number) - but I can`t see them ?!

I imported the database normal. Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the "auto increment" value of your database is gone. Try repairing it or checking it manual with a tool like PHPMyAdmin. You should check the wp_comments table, but I think you should check all tables for missing auto increment info.

Comment: You should open a new question about that :)